# iOS Material Component flexible header, button not clickable

Tags: ios, swift, material-components, material-components-ios

I am building an app where i need to have flexible header above collection view. 
I have implemented Material Component Flexible header and added a header view from xib 
Here is my code

```
let heroHeaderView = HeroHeaderView()
self.addChildViewController(appBar.headerViewController)
appBar.headerViewController.layoutDelegate = self
let headerView = appBar.headerViewController.headerView
headerView.backgroundColor = .clear
headerView.maximumHeight = HeroHeaderView.Constants.maxHeight
headerView.minimumHeight = HeroHeaderView.Constants.minHeight

heroHeaderView.frame = headerView.bounds
headerView.insertSubview(heroHeaderView, at: 0)
headerView.canOverExtend = false
headerView.trackingScrollView = self.collectionView
```

In xib i have added two buttons. ibaction for both not getting called.
if i do `headerView.bringSubview(toFront: heroHeaderView)` those buttons ibaction get called but it hides my appbar.
How can i have both appbar and buttons touches

Comment: have you created appBar on xib? have you provide any constraint between heroHeaderview and appbar?

Comment: No. i have not created app bar on xib. its default appBar created with
`appBar.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear
    appBar.headerViewController.layoutDelegate = self
    appBar.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
    appBar.navigationBar.title = "Title" `